# Maximum call stack exceeded when importing a module from another module

Tags: angular, module, components

I am quite new to Angular but I have the following issue:

I created a module called `ModuleA` that declares and exports `ComponentA`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ComponentA],
  exports: [ComponentA]
})
```

I then attempt to import `ModuleA` into `ModuleB` so that I can access `ComponentA`

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule, ModuleA],
    declarations: [ComponentB]
})
```

I then receive the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

ModuleA and ModuleB are both declared in app.module.ts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by creating a shared module that imports both `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`